# Small web service, gdpr, privacy policy etc

Tags: google-analytics, gdpr, privacy-policy

I have created a simple API based service for developers. And I am stacked for a few days with gdpr and legal stuff.

1. I am using firebase auth, to track users and API usage.
2. I want to show an ads from a Google AdWords.
3. I am collect google analytics on website.

I checked tons of information in internet. And found a lot of things that should to be done.

- cookie contest
- privacy policy
- Delete account process
- Possibility to request all data for user.
- Store cookie contest results

It is quite complex to follow all of this rules. I there some way to optimize it. Example to use google analytics and adsense without cookies.

Is there some frameworks that could cover all the questions. And can be easily settled up on a site?
Do I miss something in a list?
Do I really need to follow all of this rules, or it is applicable only for a big companies?

Comment: I think the data needs to be stored and processed in servers in Europe.